# Can Jenkins pipeline function fileExist handle wildcards?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, file-exists

Can Jenkins pipeline function fileExist handle wildcards?
I do have a zip file in the workspace folder. Following code gives `hifalse`:

```
WORKSPACE = pwd()
echo "hi"+fileExists("${WORKSPACE}/*.zip*")
```

but then how can I do it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`fileExists` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace) accepts neither wildcards, nor absolute paths.

However, if you install the optional [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps), you can make use of the [`findFiles` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace), which does accept wildcards. For example:

```java
def files = findFiles glob: '**/*.zip'
boolean exists = files.length > 0
```

As an alternative, without that plugin, you could use a shell step to run `find`:

```java
def exitCode = sh script: 'find -name "*.zip" | egrep .', returnStatus: true
boolean exists = exitCode == 0
```

Comment: You mean fileExists("${WORKSPACE}/abc.zip") does not work?

Comment: @BimleshSharma That won't work as it has an absolute path. Without the absolute path, it would work. But it's unrelated to the question, where someone is trying to use wildcards.