# Read a .csv file on the workspace without specifying its name

Tags: jenkins, groovy

A .csv file from another job is being copied into my job's workspace.

Since the .csv file name changes every day, how can I read it without specifying its name?

It's the only .csv file in the folder.

```
copyArtifacts(projectName: 'scanPinnedVersions')
def lastSuccessBuildNum = Jenkins.instance.getItem("scanPinnedVersions").lastSuccessfulBuild.displayName.replace("#","")
def da = readFile WORKSPACE + "/" + lastSuccessBuildNum + '/scanPinnedVersionReport.2021-12-05-080054.csv'
```

> scanPinnedVersionReport.2021-12-05-080054.csv

Needs to be:

> scanPinnedVersionReport*.csv

Thanks for helping. I would love to learn how to do this.

Comment: Maybe use findFiles first? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729669/6509

Answer (score -1):

Using `findFiles` you should be able to accomplish this. [Link to Jenkins doc.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace)

It will return a list of files (in this case, sounds like only one) and you can then process it accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).