# How to handle wildcards in `fileExists()` function without Plugins in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins declarative pipeline syntax and I need to check if a file exists. Otherwise it should abort the current stage. The problem I encounter is that the file contains a timestamp which is different every time the build process runs.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722685/can-jenkins-pipeline-function-fileexist-handle-wildcards) thread. But sadly they use a plugin I dont have access to, so it does not fit my problem.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    stage('Check if file exists') {
        steps {
            script {
                if(fileExists('./path/to/file/name_1234567890.tar.gz')) {
                    currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
                    error('Could not find file!')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your OS build is linux or windows, I think you can use bash script or powershell and save stdout and compare with groovy script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findFiles` which allows glob syntax:

```
stage('Check if file exists') {
        steps {
            script {
                def any_files = false
                def output_files = findFiles glob: './path/to/file/name_*.tar.gz'
                for (def one_file in output_files) { any_files = true; break }
                if (any_files) { // or maybe (!any_files) 
                    currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
                    error('Could not find file!')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```